# Programmatically get Bluetooth LE transmission power of my Android phone

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I want to get the Bluetooth LE transmission power level of my own phone programmatically (so without manually measuring it).

It should be possible to get the value without measurements since one can request to include the TX Power level in advertisement packets by using [`AdvertiseData.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder.html#setIncludeTxPowerLevel(boolean)).

I would like to directly get this value so I can include it in my own advertisement packets (e.g. for Eddystone or iBeacon format, ...)

Some ideas about how I can get that?